# Memory error while solving an anagram

Tags: python, memory, anagram

I am trying to solve the below question:

An anagram is a type of word play, the result of rearranging the letters of a word or phrase to produce a new word or phrase, using all the original letters exactly once; e.g., orchestra = carthorse. Using the word list at http://www.puzzlers.org/pub/wordlists/unixdict.txt, write a program that finds the sets of words that share the same characters that contain the most words in them.

It's failing even with just 1000 bytes of file size. Also every time a new list is created, so why does Python keep the old list in memory? I am getting the below error.

```
l=list(map(''.join, itertools.permutations(i)))
```

gives me:

```
MemoryError
```

Here's my code:

```
import itertools
def anagram():
    f=open('unixdict.txt')
    f2=open('result_anagram.txt','w')
    words = f.read(1000).split('\n')
    for i in words:
        l=[]
        l=list(map(''.join, itertools.permutations(i)))
        l.remove(i)
        for anagram in l:
            if l==i:
                f2.write(i + "\n")
    return True

anagram()
```

Changed the above code to, as per suggestion. But still getting the memory error.

```
import itertools

def anagram():
    f=open('unixdict.txt')
    f2=open('result_anagram.txt','w')
    words = set(line.rstrip('\n') for line in f)
    for i in words:
        l= map(''.join, itertools.permutations(i))
        l =(x for x in l if x!=i)
        for anagram in l:
            if anagram in words:
                f2.write(i + "\n")
    return True

anagram()
```

MemoryError
 [Finished in 22.2s]

Comment: why are you creating a list `l = []` and then reassigning `l = list(map...?` Also what is `list(map(''.join, itertools.permutations(i)))` actually doing?

Comment: Yes, removed the list function. thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This program is going to be horribly inefficient no matter what you do.

But you can fix this `MemoryError` so it'll just take forever to run instead of failing.

First, note that a 12-letter word has 479,001,600 permutations. Storing all of those in memory is going to take more than 2GB of memory. So, how do you solve that? Just don't store them all in memory. Leave the iterator as an iterator instead of making a list, and then you'll only have to fit one at a time, instead of all of them.

There's one problem here: You're actually using that list in the `if l==i:` line. But clearly that's a mistake. There's no way that a list of strings can ever equal a single string. You might as well replace that line with `raise TypeError`, at which point you can just replace the whole loop and fail a whole lot faster. :)

I *think* what you wanted there is `if anagram in words:`. In which case you have no need for `l`, except for in the `for` loop, which means you can safely leave it as a lazy iterator:

```
for i in words:
    l = map(''.join, itertools.permutations(i))
    l = (x for x in l if x != i)
    for anagram in l:
        if anagram in words:
            f2.write(i + "\n")
```

I'm assuming Python 3.x here, since otherwise the `list` call was completely unnecessary. If you're using 2.x, replace that `map` with `itertools.imap`.

---

As a side note, `f.read(1000)` is usually going to get part of an extra word at the end, and the leftover part in the next loop. Try [`readlines`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readlines). While it's useless with no argument, with an argument it's very useful:

> Read and return a list of lines from the stream. *hint* can be specified to control the number of lines read: no more lines will be read if the total size (in bytes/characters) of all lines so far exceeds *hint*.

So, `f.readlines(1000)` will let you read buffers of about 1K at a time, without getting partial lines. Of course now, instead of having to `split` on newlines, you have to `rstrip` them:

```
words = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f.readlines(1000)]
```

---

However, you've got another problem. If you're only reading about 100 words at a time, the chances of finding an anagram are pretty slim. For example, `orchestra` is not going to be anywhere near `carthorse` in the dictionary, so there's no way to find unless you remember the entire file. But that should be fine; a typical Unix dictionary like web2 has around 200K lines; you an easily read that into memory and keep it around as a `set` without making even a dent on your 2GB. So:

```
words = set(line.rstrip('\n') for line in f)
```

---

Also, note that you're trying to print out every word in the dictionary that has an anagram (multiple times, if it has multiple anagrams). Even with an efficient algorithm, that's going to take a long time—and spew out more data than you could possibly want. A more useful program might be one that takes an input word (e.g., via `input` or `sys.argv[1]`) and outputs just the anagrams of that word.

---

Finally:

> Even after using l as a generator it taking up too much off time though no failing with memory error. Can you explain the importance of words as a set rather than a list. [Finished in 137.4s] just for 200 bytes, you have mentioned it before, but how to overcome it using words as set?

As I said at the top, "This program is going to be horribly inefficient no matter what you do."

In order to find the anagrams of a 12-letter word, you're going through 479 million permutations, and checking each one against a dictionary of about 200 thousand words, so that's 479M * 200K = 95 *trillion* checks, for each word. There are two ways to improve this, the first involving using the right data structures for the job, and the second involving the right algorithms for the job.

Changing the collection of things to iterate over from a list into a generator (a lazy iterable) turns something that took linear space (479M strings) into something that takes constant space (some fixed-size iterator state, plus one string at a time). Similarly, changing the collection of words to check against from a list into a set turns something that takes linear time (comparing a string against every element in the list) into something that takes constant time (hashing a string, then seeing if there's anything in the set with that hash value). So, this gets rid of the `* 200K` part of your problem.

But you've still got the `479M` part of the problem. And you can't make that go away with a better data structure. Instead, you have to rethink the problem. How can you check whether any permutation of a word matches any other words, without trying all the permutations?

Well, some permutation of the word X matches the word Y if and only if X and Y have the same letters. It doesn't matter what order the letters in X were in; if the set is the same, there is at least one matching permutation (or exactly one, depending on how you count duplicate letters), and if not, there are exactly 0. So, instead of iterating through all the permutations in the word to look up, just look up its set. But it does matter if there are duplicates, so you can't just use `set` here. You could use some kind of multi-set (`collections.Counter`) works… or, with very little loss in efficiency and a big gain in simplicity, you could just sort the letters. After all, if two words have the same letters in some arbitrary order, they have the same letters in the same order when they're both sorted.

Of course you need to know *which* words are anagrams, not just that there *is* an anagram, so you can't just look it up in a set of letter sets, you have to look it up in a dictionary that maps letter sets to words. For example, something like this:

```
lettersets = collections.defaultdict(set)
for word in words:
    lettersets[''.join(sorted(word))].add(word)
```

So now, to look up the anagrams for a word, all you have to do is:

```
anagrams = lettersets[''.join(sorted(word))]
```

Not only is that simple and readable, it's also constant-time.

And if you really want to print out the massive list of all anagrams of all words… well, that's easy too:

```
for _, words in lettersets.items():
    for word in words:
        print('{} is an anagram of {}'.format(word, ', '.join(words - {word})))
```

Now, instead of taking 479M*200K time to find anagrams for one word, or 479M*200K*200K time to find all anagrams for all words, it takes constant time to find anagrams for one word, or 200K time to find all anagrams for all words. (Of course there is 200K setup time added to the start to create the mapping, but spending 200K time up-front to save 200K, much less 479M*200K, time for each lookup is an obvious win.)

Things get a little trickier when you want to, e.g., find partial anagrams, or sentence anagarms, but you want to follow the same basic principles: find data structures that let you do things in constant or logarithmic time instead of linear or worse, and find algorithms that don't require you to brute-force your way through an exponential or factorial number of candidates.

Comment: Thanks, I just didn't realize that 12 letter word would have so many permutations. Also got to know the importance of generators. yes wanted to do anagram in words

Comment: Even after using l as a generator it taking up too much off time though no failing with memory error. Can you explain the importance of words as a set rather than a list. [Finished in 137.4s] just for 200 bytes, you have mentioned it before, but how to overcome it using words as set?

Answer (score 2):

```
import urllib

def anagram():
    f=urllib.urlopen('http://www.puzzlers.org/pub/wordlists/unixdict.txt')
    words = f.read().split('\n')

    d={''.join(sorted(x)):[]  for x in words}   #create dic with empty list as default
    for x in words:
        d[''.join(sorted(x))].append(x)

    max_len= max( len(v) for k,v in d.iteritems())

    for k,v in d.iteritems():
        if len(v)>=max_len:
            print v

anagram()
```

Output:

```
['abel', 'able', 'bale', 'bela', 'elba']
['alger', 'glare', 'lager', 'large', 'regal']
['angel', 'angle', 'galen', 'glean', 'lange']
['evil', 'levi', 'live', 'veil', 'vile']
['caret', 'carte', 'cater', 'crate', 'trace']
['elan', 'lane', 'lean', 'lena', 'neal']
```

Finished in 5.7 secs

Comment: nice and short, awesome

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint on solving the problem: two strings are anagrams of each other if they have the same collection of letters. You can *sort* the words (turning e.g. "orchestra" into "acehorrst"), then just see two words have the same sorted order. If they do, then the original words must have been anagrams of each other, since they have all the same letters (in a different order).